# wal-e backup-push error on Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage, wal-e

I am getting the following error on executing the backup-push command:

```
# envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main

 wal_e.main   INFO     MSG: starting WAL-E
    DETAIL: The subcommand is "backup-push".
    STRUCTURED: time=2017-06-14T21:33:56.131389-00 pid=17559
 wal_e.main   CRITICAL MSG: An unprocessed exception has avoided all error handling
    DETAIL: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wal_e/blobstore/wabs/wabs_util.py", line 27, in <module>
        from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
    ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wal_e/cmd.py", line 589, in main
        backup_cxt = configure_backup_cxt(args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wal_e/cmd.py", line 504, in configure_backup_cxt
        from wal_e.blobstore import wabs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wal_e/blobstore/wabs/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from wal_e.blobstore.wabs.wabs_util import do_lzop_get
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wal_e/blobstore/wabs/wabs_util.py", line 29, in <module>
        from azure.storage import BlobService
    ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService'

    STRUCTURED: time=2017-06-14T21:33:56.356868-00 pid=17559
```

I have already tried updated Python and Azure

wal-e version: 1.0.3
SO: Ubuntu Server 16.4.1 LTS

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, and I reviewed the source code of the `wal-e` version `1.0.3`, then I discovered the issue was caused by the `wal-e` version `1.0.3` actually required the `azure-storage` version less than `0.20.3`, but installed the latest `azure-storage` version `0.34.3` when you were installing via `pip3 install wal-e[azure]`. Please check your current version of `azure-storage` via `pip3 freeze | grep azure-storage`.

So there are two solution for resolving the issue, as below.

1. Downgrade the `azure-storage` version to `0.20.3` via `pip3 install azure-storage==0.20.3`.
2. Or just upgrade the `wal-e` version to `1.1.0b1` which required the latest `azure-storage` version and be compatible with the old version, via `pip3 install wal-e==1.1.0b1`.

Hope it helps.